# Why does the SSH RSA signature change frequently

Tags: remote, raspbian-buster

I am running a couple of servers on my Raspberry Pi 3, and have access to it via both VNC and SFTP.
The Pi is sometimes shutdown very frequently (while testing code), if this is relevant.

The problem is that the Pi keeps generating new signatures for itself.
Some tools (e.g. VNC Viewer, FileZilla) warn about the change and allow to trust it, while other tools don't seem to even give the option.

I installed Raspbian from NOOBS, have it running the new buster, and didn't configure much else in regards to SSH other than enabling it via the Pi's settings following a tutorial.

Is there a reason the signature keeps changing?

Can I stop the signature from changing?

And finally, is there a better way to handle remote connections in the first place?

Comment: You say, "The problem is that "it"..." Could you please define what "it" is exactly? Also, without fully understanding your question, I will hazard a guess that [the knowledge you seek is in this post.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9896/how-does-rsa-signature-verification-work) Read it, and then modify your question so that it's a little more specific. We'll try to help.

Comment: "It" being the Raspberry, using the SSH library installed with it. While the linked post was interesting, it's not quite directly related. The issue is that upon connecting to the Pi, many times it will use a different signature, which prompts the client to either say so and allow you to allow the connection to go through, or worse simply not allow you to connect

Comment: The ssh keys in /etc/ssh or ~/.ssh will not change unless you change them. You need to explain what you are doing and the exact error message if you want any answers.

Comment: Apologies, but I feel you'll need to supply more info/details to improve your chances of getting a helpful answer. Have you generated the public&private key pairs on your RPi? Are you talking about the file(s) in /home/pi/.ssh???

Comment: @user2503048, the first comment asked you to clarify the meaning of the word `it` .... please edit your question with the clarification ... your question needs to be clear on its own, without explanations in comments